# Query to Get Accounts doesn't collide with Date range

Tags: sql

Accounts table has fields Accounts,startdate and enddate. Same account will have different start date and end date. 
I need get account that fall in same date range.

Table

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| Account  | StartDate |  Enddate   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| T001     | 1/1/2018  | 6/30/2018  |
| T001     | 7/1/2018  | 12/31/2018 |
| T002     | 1/1/2018  | 6/1/2018   |
| T002     | 7/1/2018  | 12/31/2018 |
| T002     | 4/1/2018  | 6/5/2018   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Expected

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| Account  | StartDate |  Enddate   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| T002     | 1/1/2018  | 6/1/2018   |
| T002     | 7/1/2018  | 12/31/2018 |
| T002     | 4/1/2018  | 6/5/2018   |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Here T002 accounts date range collide.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  The logic you need is also really unclear.  Why not just use `where account = 'T002'`?  What is the date range you are talking about?

Comment: why not `T1`? The account `T1` collides with `T2` too. For me it is not clear what you mean by *I need get account that fall in same date range*.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM account_table t1 
INNER JOIN account_table t2 
ON t1.Account=t2.Account 
AND t1.StartDate<t2.EndDate 
AND t1.EndDate>t2.StartDate 
AND t1.StartDate<>t2.StartDate;
```

this will get all the accounts with overlapped date range.